# Animation on a HTML5 mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a mobile website and I'm using javascript to animate things around? Is this recommended or should I use CSS3 transitions?

If so how can I implement a simple CSS3 transition that will move `divA` down `20px` when `divA` is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a combination of javascript and CSS. CSS for the animations and javascript to trigger them.

Take a look at this jQuery plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

I've been using it recently and it is very useful, especially for callbacks.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think using JQuery and a plugin for a basic transition may be too much on a mobile website (where speed counts.)

Comment: I would agree, for something small, but for repeated use across a site that plugin is pretty handy. All it does it take care of cross browser compatibility issues with vendor prefixes and provide callbacks. Anything unsupported falls back to the default jQuery animate function.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use jQuery + a plugin just to move down a div on a mobile device.
CSS3 transitions and animations are very well supported on mobile devices, on some of them even hardware accelerated.

Here is a simple script that does what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Sd4U/

Comment: Oh, the correct way to do it if you don't have dynamic variables would be to just add a class with all the CSS code .

Comment: I've had some experience with this recently, and I'd usually agree, but mobile safari has a real performance issue when things get a bit more complicated. Adding a class to a container with lots of content for example forces it to check that it doesn't have to re-render anything inside. This can lead to a considerable delay before it animates anything.